# Can't migrate Metadata (AWS::CloudFormation::Init) section of existing CloudFormation template into AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm setting up an ADFS EC2 instance using AWS CDK.

I can't find any understandable information regarding metadata in the documentation.

I tried **cdk-dasm** tool to reverse engineer it, but it misses out on the metadata section.

How can I add sections under **AWS::CloudFormation::Init**?

I'm reffering the aws-quickstart repo:

https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-microsoft-activedirectory/blob/master/templates/Template_1_AD_2012R2.template

Below is the section I'm trying to convert, will appreciate any help!

```
    DomainController1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          config:
          - setup
          - rename
          - installADDS
          - configureSites
          - installADCS
          - finalize
        setup:
          files:
            c:\cfn\cfn-hup.conf:
              content:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - "[main]\n"
                  - stack=
                  - Ref: AWS::StackName
                  - "\n"
                  - region=
                  - Ref: AWS::Region
                  - "\n"
            c:\cfn\hooks.d\cfn-auto-reloader.conf:
              content:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n"
                  - 'triggers=post.update\n'
                  - 'path=Resources.DomainController1.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n'
                  - 'action=cfn-init.exe -v -c config -s '
                  - Ref: AWS::StackId
                  - " -r DomainController1"
                  - " --region "
                  - Ref: AWS::Region
                  - "\n"
            c:\cfn\scripts\Set-StaticIP.ps1:
              content:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - "$netip = Get-NetIPConfiguration;"
                  - "$ipconfig = Get-NetIPAddress | ?{$_.IpAddress -eq $netip.IPv4Address.IpAddress};"
                  - Get-NetAdapter | Set-NetIPInterface -DHCP Disabled;
                  - Get-NetAdapter | New-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -IPAddress
                    $netip.IPv4Address.IpAddress -PrefixLength $ipconfig.PrefixLength
                    -DefaultGateway $netip.IPv4DefaultGateway.NextHop;
                  - Get-NetAdapter | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses $netip.DNSServer.ServerAddresses;
                  - "\n"
            c:\cfn\scripts\bootstrap.ps1:
              content:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - "Import-Module GroupPolicy"
                  - "\n"
                  - 'try{ Invoke-WebRequest https://s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/vocera-boxes-ic5vda9lly/open/DefaultDomainPolicy.zip -OutFile c:\DefaultDomainPolicy.zip'
                  - "\n"
                  - 'powershell.exe -command c:\cfn\scripts\Unzip-Archive.ps1 -Source "c:\DefaultDomainPolicy.zip" -Destination "C:\" }'
                  - "\n"
                  - 'catch {}'
                  - "\n"
                  - 'import-gpo -BackupGpoName "Default Domain Policy" -TargetName "Default Domain Policy" -path C:\DefaultDomainPolicy'
                  - "\n"
                  - 'gpupdate /force'
                  - "\n"
            c:\cfn\scripts\cis_changes.ps1:
              source: https://url.com/cis_changes.ps1
            'c:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Settings\config.xml':
              source: https://url.com/cis_config.xml
            c:\cfn\scripts\ConvertTo-EnterpriseAdmin.ps1:
              source: https://url.com/ConvertTo-EnterpriseAdmin.ps1
            c:\cfn\scripts\New-CertificateAuthority.ps1:
              source: https://url.com/New-CertificateAuthority.ps1
            c:\cfn\modules\xAdcsDeployment_0.1.0.0.zip:
              source: https://url.com/xAdcsDeployment_0.1.0.0.zip
            c:\cfn\scripts\Unzip-Archive.ps1:
              source: https://url.com/Unzip-Archive.ps1
          services:
            windows:
              cfn-hup:
                enabled: 'true'
                ensureRunning: 'true'
                files:
                - c:\cfn\cfn-hup.conf
                - c:\cfn\hooks.d\cfn-auto-reloader.conf
          commands:
            a-allow-hostname-update:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - powershell.exe -Command c:\cfn\scripts\cis_changes.ps1
              waitAfterCompletion: '45'
            a-disable-win-fw:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - powershell.exe -Command "Get-NetFirewallProfile | Set-NetFirewallProfile
                    -Enabled False"
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
            b-set-execution-policy:
              command: powershell.exe -command Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
            c-unpack-dsc-resource:
              command: powershell.exe -command c:\cfn\scripts\Unzip-Archive.ps1 -Source
                c:\cfn\modules\xAdcsDeployment_0.1.0.0.zip -Destination 'C:\Program
                Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
        rename:
          commands:
            a-set-static-ip:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command c:\cfn\scripts\Set-StaticIP.ps1
              waitAfterCompletion: '45'
            b-execute-powershell-script-RenameComputer:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - 'powershell.exe Rename-Computer -NewName '
                  - 'DC1'
                  - " -Restart"
              waitAfterCompletion: forever
        installADDS:
          commands:
            1-install-prereqs:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - powershell.exe -Command "Install-WindowsFeature AD-Domain-Services,
                    rsat-adds -IncludeAllSubFeature"
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
            2-install-adds:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - 'powershell.exe -Command '
                  - "\"Install-ADDSForest -DomainName "
                  - Ref: DomainDNSName
                  - " "
                  - "-SafeModeAdministratorPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "
                  - "'"
                  - Ref: VcaADPassword
                  - "'"
                  - " -AsPlainText -Force) "
                  - "-DomainMode Win2012R2 "
                  - "-DomainNetbiosName "
                  - Ref: DomainNetBIOSName
                  - " "
                  - "-ForestMode Win2012R2 "
                  - "-Confirm:$false "
                  - -Force"
              waitAfterCompletion: forever
            3-restart-service:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - powershell.exe -Command Restart-Service NetLogon -EA 0
              waitAfterCompletion: '30'
            4-create-adminuser:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - 'powershell.exe -Command '
                  - "\"New-ADUser "
                  - "-Name "
                  - Ref: ADUSER
                  - " "
                  - "-UserPrincipalName "
                  - Ref: ADUSER
                  - "@"
                  - Ref: DomainDNSName
                  - " "
                  - "-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "
                  - "'"
                  - Ref: VcaADPassword
                  - "'"
                  - " -AsPlainText -Force) "
                  - "-Enabled $true "
                  - -PasswordNeverExpires $true"
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
            5-update-adminuser:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command c:\cfn\scripts\ConvertTo-EnterpriseAdmin.ps1
                    -Members '
                  - Ref: ADUSER
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
        configureSites:
          commands:
            a-rename-default-site:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - 'powershell.exe '
                  - "\""
                  - Get-ADObject -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).ConfigurationNamingContext
                    -filter {Name -eq 'Default-First-Site-Name'} | Rename-ADObject -NewName
                    AZ1
                  - "\""
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
            b-create-site-2:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - powershell.exe New-ADReplicationSite AZ2
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
            c-create-publicsubnet-1:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - 'powershell.exe -Command New-ADReplicationSubnet -Name '
                  - 172.30.209.0/24
                  - " -Site AZ1"
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
            d-create-publicsubnet-2:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - 'powershell.exe -Command New-ADReplicationSubnet -Name '
                  - 172.30.210.0/24
                  - " -Site AZ2"
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
            e-create-privatesubnet-1:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - 'powershell.exe -Command New-ADReplicationSubnet -Name '
                  - 172.30.212.0/24
                  - " -Site AZ1"
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
            f-create-privatesubnet-2:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - 'powershell.exe -Command New-ADReplicationSubnet -Name '
                  - 172.30.213.0/24
                  - " -Site AZ2"
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
            g-set-site-link:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - powershell.exe -Command "
                  - Get-ADReplicationSiteLink -Filter * | Set-ADReplicationSiteLink
                    -SitesIncluded @{add='AZ2'} -ReplicationFrequencyInMinutes 15"
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
        installADCS:
          commands:
            a-install-ca:
              command:
                Fn::Join:
                - ''
                - - 'powershell.exe -Command c:\cfn\scripts\New-CertificateAuthority.ps1
                    -Username '
                  - Ref: ADUSER
                  - " -Password "
                  - "'"
                  - Ref: ADPassword
                  - "'"
                  - " -DomainDNSName "
                  - Ref: DomainDNSName
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
            b-update-gpo:
              command: powershell.exe -command c:\cfn\scripts\bootstrap.ps1
              waitAfterCompletion: '0'
    Properties:
      DisableApiTermination: False
      ImageId:
        Fn::FindInMap:
        - AmiMap
        - Ref: AWS::Region
        - win2012r2
      InstanceType: t2.large
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Ref: ADProfile
      SubnetId: subnet-11111111
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value:
          Fn::Join: [ "_", [ "ee" , Ref: EnvironmentType,"AD","1" ] ]
      -
        Key: "Product"
        Value: 
          Ref: Product
      - 
        Key: "Environment"
        Value: 
          Ref: EnvironmentType
      - 
        Key: "Role"
        Value: 
          Ref: Role
      BlockDeviceMappings:
      - DeviceName: "/dev/sda1"
        Ebs:
          VolumeSize: '150'
          VolumeType: gp2
      SecurityGroupIds:
      - Ref: DomainControllerSG
      - sg-0000
      PrivateIpAddress:
        Ref: Server1PrivateIP
      KeyName:
        Ref: SSHkeyPair
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - "<script>\n"
            - 'cfn-init.exe -v -c config -s '
            - Ref: AWS::StackId
            - " -r DomainController1"
            - " --region "
            - Ref: AWS::Region
            - "\n"
            - "</script>\n"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To attach metadata that is synthesized and attached to resources, you need to add it as an explicit override. The `.addMetadata` method only adds internal CDK metadata that is not synthesized.

Eg:

```js
instance.addOverride('Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init', {
  config: {
    files: {
      '/root/run-iperf.sh': {
        content: runIperfScript,
        mode: '000755',
        owner: 'root',
        group: 'root'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: We scrapped the idea of using CDK for ADFS. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add metadata to a CDK construct by accessing the underlying node.

```js
const instance = new ec2.Instance(this, "MyInstance", {...});
instance.node.addMetadata("key", "value");
```

Here is the documentation for `ConstructNode.addMetadata`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.ConstructNode.html#add-wbr-metadatatype-data-from

Comment: This doesn't actually synthesize and attach - see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61895033/1042